# Cannot find field in mongo collection using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, morphia

I have an abstract Scala class as a Mongo collection.

```
@Entity("aclTemplate")
abstract class AclTemplate(@(Id@field) var id: String) extends Serializable
```

Another class extends the above

```
@Entity("aclTemplate")
class GroupACLTemplate(id: String, var groupRoleAccess: Set[GroupRoleAccess]) extends AclTemplate(id) with Serializable
```

There are some docs of `GroupACLTemplate` in the collection. I am trying a simple query

```
createQuery().disableValidation().field("groupRoleAccess.groupId").equal(groupId).asList();
```

This throws a `ValidationException`

```
org.mongodb.morphia.query.ValidationException: The field 'groupRoleAccess.groupId' could not be found in 'com.model.acl.AclTemplate'
```

I do not think it is because of the long standing polymorphism issue in morphia. Because when I try to access just `groupRoleAccess`, it is able to. However, it is not able to access inside that set. It is a normal Java set. This is the `GroupRoleAccess` class

```
class GroupRoleAccess(var groupId: String, var roleId: String) extends Serializable
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hack something up. Apparently, since the collection is an abstract class, Mongo/Morphia does not look for attributes that are present in its subclasses. So I used `createQuery` and passed the class of the subclass.

```
ds.createQuery(clazz).disableValidation().field("groupRoleAccess.groupId").equal(groupId).asList();
```

But I still wonder how it was able to extract `groupRoleAccess` before

Answer (score 0):

You should try `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT`.  I just fixed a bug similar to this and it probably fixes your issue, too.